# PHP: Insert two rows into mySQL database won´t work. What´s wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m trying to insert in a single query two rows into two different columns, that belongs to a single database.

```
$consultaModifica="INSERT into zona(zona1,zona2,zona3)
VALUES('$z1','$z2','$z3');
INSERT into ubicacgeo(geoA,geoB,geoC,geoD)
VALUES('$gA','$gB','$gC');
";
```

It won´t work with two cols. Now this one does work:

```
$consultaModifica="INSERT into zona(zona1,zona2,zona3)
VALUES('$z1','$z2','$z3')
";
```

I´ve tried usig ; after finishing VALUES(), and not using it, with the same result: It won´t tell me about any errors, but it won´t insert nothing into the database.

The question is, then, how to insert more than one value into more than one column? 
The cols are MyISAM type.

I´ve read some answers here in SO, but haven´t found any that actually works with MyISAM databases.

Comment: You are trying to insert into two different tables. Therefore require two queries.

Comment: agreed with @Ed Heal and also you need to a blank or null here `INSERT into ubicacgeo(geoA,geoB,geoC,geoD)
VALUES('$gA','$gB','$gC', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run 2 insert query for 2 different tables so you need to execute query for 2 times like this

```
<?php
$consultaModifica=mysql_query("INSERT into zona(zona1,zona2,zona3)
VALUES('$z1','$z2','$z3')");

$consultaModifica2 = mysql_query("INSERT into ubicacgeo(geoA,geoB,geoC,geoD)
VALUES('$gA','$gB','$gC','')");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't enter two different queries like you have in your question. You need to break these out into two separate `mysql_query` commands for it to work.

```
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

If it was the same table for both, you could combine them... but here you can't.